# how long can H.Pylori last if not cured?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, stomach, bacteria, ulcers, h.-helycobacter-pylori

Is it possible for H.Pylori to last for 10 years if not cured properly?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course.

**Helycobacter Pylorii** is a gram- bacteria which live is acid envronment, like stomach or duodenum.

Common thoughts are that since stomach is acid, HP should die during time. This is not true, because this bacteria has different "weapons" to survive:

-*urease*: this enzyme uses urea in the stomach to produce ammonia and HCO3-(bicarbonate), that neutralize the acid of the stomach;

-*motility*: this bacteria can move: this prevent acid to attack it;

-specific proteins (*adhesins*): which allows the bacteria to attach to the side of the mucous membrane.

Then, making other enzymes, like "*vacA*" and "*cagA*", can damage your stomach/duodenum wall and enter, causing the well known ulcers.

This bacteria is also important in the genesis of *gastric cancer*, if it is not treat.

**Diagnosis** is really simple:

-*invasive methods*: with an endoscopy, doctor take a "bite" of the mucous wall and make both histological research, culture or test with urea (if needed, I can explain better later)

-*not invasive*: urea breath test, feces test, serology IgG anti HP

**Therapy** is simple as well:

-proton pump inhibitors(PPI) + clarithromycin + metronidazole or amoxicillin for 2weeks

-if clarithromycin resistance: PPI + tetracycline + bismuth + metronidazole

This is called "sequential therapy"; there is also the triple therapy, but researches prove that sequential is effective.

---

Ref.

- [Chapter 151 of the Harrison's principles of Internal Medicine](http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/content.aspx?bookid=331&sectionid=40726901)
- [Treatment of H. pylori infection: the reality.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2578890/)

Comment: Please add some references

Comment: @L.B. Added references

Comment: @Gabri Why don't you take a picture of the *Harrison Principles of IM* and include it in your answer, as not everyone has this book. Also, *"personal notes"* are not considered as reference! See [meta].

Comment: @Narusan I don't have the english version, so the problem is the same. I try to search on internet.
As with "personal notes" I refer to my profession, and I think it's a reference. I can agree with you that you can't verify I'm a doctor, so I remove it.
Thanks for your comment!

Comment: I've found a reference on the web and I've attached.

Comment: A good answer and great job on the references, +1. I fixed a few typos and tweaked the formatting of the references, to make everything look a bit neater (hope you don't mind).